# from Keras.layers.core import Dense using theano as backend when creating a model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, theano

I have imported Dense from keras.layers.core ,When I create a new model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))
```

then there is an error

```
AttributeError:('The following error happened while compiling the node', 
DotModulo(A, s, m, A2, s2, m2), '\n', 
"module 'numpy.core.multiarray' has no attribute '_get_ndarray_c_version'")
```

I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of `theano` is too old for the version of `numpy` you have, so you get these errors, but the solution is simple, you should upgrade to `theano >= 1.0.4` (at least version 1.0.4) which should solve the issue, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/3340).

Also note that Theano is not really being developed anymore, so issues like this will become more common, you should consider migrating to another backend.

Comment: Thanks ,I installed keras on a new environment without having to use theano,to avoid the contradiction